# Read the data of the CSV file uploaded from the user

Tags: python, csv, web, flask

I'm trying to write a Python/Flask script that transforms a csv file into some other file. I've developed a UI so that user can upload a CSV file. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to read the data of that CSV file, uploaded from the user.

```
@app.route('/import', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files['file']
            if not file.filename:
                errors.append("Please select a file!")
            else:
                ...
                data = [GET CSV DATA HERE]
                process_data(data)
```

How could I get the data from the CSV file so that I could pass on the following method:

```
def process_data(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would swap the if statement logic around.

```
if file.filename:
    csv_file = request.files["file"]
    data = [GET CSV DATA HERE]
    process_data(data)
else:
    errors.append("Please select a file!")

#You could also have elif before the else to ensure
#that the requirement is met
elif file.filename:
    pass
```

This makes more sense, only if the file is present or been uploaded in your case, should the file read attempt be made. If the file was not uploaded but there was a post request, let's say, someone uploaded the wrong file type, this would cause an error which would drop the script / app execution.

The file is already present in the request, but her is a simple example that you should easily be able to wrap your head around considering how far you've managed to get so far.

https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/30/how-to-upload-and-process-the-csv-file-in-django/

Comment: Hello @Swift! Thank you for your answer! I have additional user inputs, that's why I'm checking first if there are errors, so that I can gather them all together. And the process_data() method is not in there, but for the sake of simplicity I put it there. Thank you for the the link.

Comment: Don't forget to answer if it satisfies your question.

Comment: Hello @Swift! Sorry for forgetting to mark your answer as helpful!

Comment: No worries dude, we all like to get cracking when we find answers to burning questions. Hence why were here